# Can I simplify this iOS renderer now that I no longer need to explicitly subscribe to property-changed-event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this custom renderer:

```
public class ExtViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    UITableViewCell _nativeCell;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        _nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        var formsCell = item as ExtViewCell;

        if (formsCell != null)
        {
            formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
            formsCell.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }
        SetTap(formsCell);

        return _nativeCell;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var formsCell = sender as ExtViewCell;
        if (formsCell == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == ExtViewCell.NoTapProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetTap(formsCell);
        }
    }

    private void SetTap(ExtViewCell formsCell)
    {
        if (formsCell.NoTap)
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        else
            _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
    }

}
```

I read that with a `TextCellRenderer` it's no longer necessary to explicitly subscribe to property-changed-event as there is a base overridable method `HandlePropertyChanged` that can be re-used in this context.

Can someone tell me if this is the case also for the `ViewCellRenderer` and if so then how could I modify this code to make use of this?

I also saw code like this in another renderer:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
{
    var textCell = (TextCell)item;
    var fullName = item.GetType().FullName;
    cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(fullName) as CellTableViewCell;

    //...
```

But not here.  Is it necessary to do this `Cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell` ?

Comment: ViewCellRenderer source: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs

Comment: TextCellRenderer source: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/TextCellRenderer.cs

Comment: `TextCellRenderer` has a `protected virtual void HandlePropertyChanged` that could be overidden, however the `ViewCellRenderer` is not exposing its `ViewCellPropertyChanged` as it is `private`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that with a TextCellRenderer it's no longer necessary to explicitly subscribe to property-changed-event as there is a base overridable method HandlePropertyChanged that can be re-used in this context.

Yes that is correct according to its source code

```
protected virtual void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    //...
}
```

[TextCellRenderer Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/TextCellRenderer.cs#L39)

> Can someone tell me if this is the case also for the ViewCellRenderer and if so then how could I modify this code to make use of this?

No it is not the case also for the `ViewCellRenderer` as according to source code [ViewCellRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs)  is not exposing its `ViewCellPropertyChanged` as it is `private`

```
void ViewCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    //...
}
```

[ViewCellRenderer Source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Cells/ViewCellRenderer.cs#L39)

You could always modify it yourself and create a pull request to add that feature.